# Installing openpyxl with python2.7 results in "ImportError : no module named util"

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I have Python 2.7.14. I know that Python 2 is deprecated but I don't have choice for the moment.

I tried to install `openpyxl` library.

I downloaded and extracted the .tar.gz. The version downloaded is 3.0.3.

When I run `python setup.py install`, I'm facing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 28, in <module>
        from importlib.util import module_from_spec, spec_from_file_location
ImportError: No module named util
```

How can I solve this issue for Python 2.7.14?

Comment: Why not do `python -m pip install openpyxl` ? From the openpyxl docs, the last compatible version for Python2.7 is [openpyxl 2.6.4](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#id16). The 3.0.3 you downloaded is Python3 only.

Comment: Oh thank you it was the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the openpyxl [release history](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#), the last version compatible with Python2.7 is 2.6.4:

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#id16

> ### 2.6.4 (2019-09-25)
>
> Final release for Python 2.7 ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

Starting openpyxl [3.0.0](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#id15), it is Python-3 only.
So, you need to install a specific older version.

Using `pip`:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.17

$ python -m pip install openpyxl==2.6.4
```

Using the downloadable tar.gz [from PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/2.6.4/#files):

```
$ wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/26/eb28e975b7a37aad38d7ec4f7a0f652bdee6ecf36e6bd06f473c5af9b87b/openpyxl-2.6.4.tar.gz
$ mkdir openpyxl-2.6.4
$ tar -xvzf openpyxl-2.6.4.tar.gz -C openpyxl-2.6.4
$ cd openpyxl-2.6.4
$ python setup.py install
```